# Best practice - depending on object key iteration order?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

In Javascript, the iteration order of an Object [is enforced](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) since ES2020 (or before, depending...).

However, is it a good idea (i.e. best practice) to depend on this?

I'm currently working on a website where the backend (NodeJS) needs to send a map of data to the front...but the keys need to follow a certain order (defined by an ordering property in the database). The front must then display the data (keys and values), *in order*. (The keys of the object are all non-numeric strings.)

While this works, the use of an object for ordered data seems like a bad idea: while the order is well-defined, it's not explicit in the datatype (usually one would use an Array for ordered data). On the other hand, if we use an Array, the keys must be included in the values, so the data loses the guarantee of key unicity.

What is the best practice here?

Comment: Though JS might have ordering, JSON objects are unordered. Use an array if you need to transfer an ordered collection.

Comment: @amon Feels to me like an expanded version of that is the answer to this question.

Comment: You can *imply* an order with suitably altered keys (`foo_1`, `bar_2` instead of just `foo`, `bar`), just as the server can verify whether the keys in an association list are unique or not. Whether to use an object or array seems like a matter of opinion, or at least dependent on which property you *most* want to preserve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The safety depends on how "closed world" your system is.

If you convert between JSON and JavaScript objects using the built-in parse/stringify functions, you can be sure key-ordering is preserved end-to-end (if no keys are numeric).

But if you introduce other languages, libraries, or endpoints, it introduces some risk of data-loss. The JSON spec defines object keys as "unordered", which mean a conformant implementation of JSON serialization/deserialization might *not* preserve key-ordering. Some languages might map an object to an unordered dictionary type.

JSON itself does not prohibit duplicate keys. Stringifying a JavaScript object cannot result in duplicate keys, but if the JSON is generated some other way (e.g. by transforming a database output) the serializer might produce JSON with duplicate keys. JSON.parse() does not alert on encountering duplicate keys, so this might lead to silent data loss at the consuming end.

Given this, I would only recommend this approach if you have a system you fully control end-to-end and everything is JavaScript. But even then I would recommend to use arrays for data with a significant ordering, since arrays clearly communicate that the ordering is significant.

Comment: Ignoring duplicate keys for the moment, you can still use an object rather than an array provided you include a "display order" property in each item. You'll need to include API documentation informing clients to do their own ordering based on the display order property. This works fine when you have a use case for a key-value data structure, but also want to give clients the information needed to keep a stable display order. But an array makes ordering things dead easy.

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Yeah but in that case I don't think there is any advantage to using an object. Just use an array and run a pass to ensure unique fields are unique. Everything is safe and explicit.